# Running pyspark application in cluster mode using jupyter notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am currently using python3.5 as kernel on jupyter notebook. I am manually importing pyspark libraries and instantiating sc,sqlcontext etc. The application is working fine but running on a single node. 
We have a six node setup in the cluster. And i want to run my application on multiple nodes.
Is there any setting which needs to be added to my application or in the jupyter notebook configuration? 
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf , SQLContext , SparkContext , HiveContext
```

`conf = SparkConf().setMaster("yarn").setAppName("test")`

```
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```